# Finding the maximum value of an id:value pair in an tuple when there are multiple of the same ids

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple that contains approximately 27,000 id:price pairs organized like this

```
((13217L, 15100004.27),
(27673L, 39070007.7),
(23133L, 7000001.03),
(31760L, 7600122.02),
(21611L, 28402830.02),
(19699L, 7500001.11),
(15753L, 50215503.2299),
(19117L, 61350002.11),
(30106L, 11121000.05),
)
```

In this giant tuple there are also multiple prices for the same id like this

```
(21611L, 28402830.02)
(21611L, 23000007.0)
(21611L, 28402653.6)
(21611L, 28403875.37)
(21611L, 28403875.38)
(21611L, 28403000.0)
(21611L, 28402845.71)
```

My question is if i wanted a new tuple/dictionary/list (doesn't really matter) that only contained the lowest of all the prices associated with a certain id or the highest of all the prices with a certain id, what would be the fastest way to do so?

Comment: what did you try? what problems did you encounter?

Comment: I'm not even sure how to approach this. I figured I would try converting it into a dictionary however when I do that the key is updated only with the last value in the tuple. I could use a for loop and append key:values into some sort of dictionary and then if it finds an existing key and the existing value is lower than the new value I could update it but I think there could be a more pythonic easier way to do it

Comment: I would do it with numpy if you want fast.  Besides 27000 is not many, even the naive approach would easily be under a second here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Fastest way" is under-specified, but you can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) on a sorted list of (ID, price) pairs:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

key = itemgetter(0)

maxprices = {id_: max(g)[1] for id_, g in groupby(sorted(pairs, key=key), key=key)}
```

Here, `pairs` would be your tuple, and `maxprices` would be a dictionary mapping IDs to highest prices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use defaultdict:

```
import random
import collections
import time

from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

# Test de N runs que guarde el nombre de cada cosa y muestre un ranking al final de todo!!

#-------------------------------------

randomPairsList=[]

for i in range(1000000):
    for j in range(1, random.randint(2,6)):
        randomPairsList.append([i,j])

sortedTuple = tuple(randomPairsList)
random.shuffle(randomPairsList)
unsortedTuple = tuple(randomPairsList)

#-------------------------------------

t0 = time.time()

key = itemgetter(0)

maxprices = {id_: min(g)[1] for id_, g in groupby(sorted(sortedTuple, key=key), key=key)}

print "groupby - SORTED:\t\t\t\t\t"+str(time.time()-t0)

#-------------------------------------

t0 = time.time()

key = itemgetter(0)

maxprices = {id_: min(g)[1] for id_, g in groupby(sorted(unsortedTuple, key=key), key=key)}

print "groupby - UNSORTED:\t\t\t\t\t"+str(time.time()-t0)

#-------------------------------------  

t0 = time.time()

d = collections.defaultdict(lambda: None)

for key, value in sortedTuple:
    d[key]=min(d[key], value)

print "\ndefaultdict (bad way) - SORTED:\t\t\t\t"+str(time.time()-t0)

#-------------------------------------  

t0 = time.time()

d = collections.defaultdict(lambda: None)

for key, value in unsortedTuple:
    d[key]=min(d[key], value)

print "defaultdict (bad way) - UNSORTED:\t\t\t"+str(time.time()-t0)

#-------------------------------------

t0 = time.time()

d = collections.defaultdict(lambda: None) # Actualizar: list si queremos append values, en este caso mejor None.

for key, value in sortedTuple:
    d[key]=min(d[key] or value, value)

print "\ndefaultdict (nicer, Python3 compatible!) - SORTED:\t"+str(time.time()-t0)

#-------------------------------------  

t0 = time.time()

d = collections.defaultdict(lambda: None) # Actualizar: list si queremos append values, en este caso mejor None.

for key, value in unsortedTuple:
    d[key]=min(d[key] or value, value)

print "defaultdict (nicer, Python3 compatible!) - UNSORTED:\t"+str(time.time()-t0)

#-------------------------------------

t0 = time.time()

d = dict()

for key, value in sortedTuple:
    d[key]=min(d.get(key, value), value)

print "\ndict (using parameter) - SORTED:\t\t\t"+str(time.time()-t0)

#-------------------------------------  

t0 = time.time()

d = dict()

for key, value in unsortedTuple:
    d[key]=min(d.get(key, value), value)

print "dict (using parameter) - UNSORTED:\t\t\t"+str(time.time()-t0)

#-------------------------------------

t0 = time.time()

d = dict()

for key, value in sortedTuple:
    d[key]=min(d.get(key) or value, value)

print "\ndict (not using parameter) - SORTED:\t\t\t"+str(time.time()-t0)

#-------------------------------------  

t0 = time.time()

d = dict()

for key, value in unsortedTuple:
    d[key]=min(d.get(key) or value, value)

print "dict (not using parameter) - UNSORTED:\t\t\t"+str(time.time()-t0)

#-------------------------------------
```

Using `groupby` is faster than `defaultdict` when the tuples are already sorted, but slower if they are not. I get these times:

```
groupby - SORTED:                                       0.796000003815
groupby - UNSORTED:                                     4.63300013542

defaultdict (bad way) - SORTED:                         1.10599994659
defaultdict (bad way) - UNSORTED:                       1.96099996567

defaultdict (nicer, Python3 compatible!) - SORTED:      1.11000013351
defaultdict (nicer, Python3 compatible!) - UNSORTED:    1.95299983025

dict (using parameter) - SORTED:                        1.23400020599
dict (using parameter) - UNSORTED:                      2.09599995613

dict (not using parameter) - SORTED:                    1.14100003242
dict (not using parameter) - UNSORTED:                  1.98699998856
```

Comment: defaultdict is not appropriate here

Comment: I've updated my answer to add a little test with the two options that have been proposed so far and a dataset of 1.000.000 IDs with 1 to 5 different prices (sorted and unsorted). With the size of your tuple both options are pretty fast, but with a larger one you can see some differences, so it's up to you choosing one or another. If you need something faster, you can check numpy as Wim suggested.

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons): *Objects of different types ... are ordered consistently but arbitrarily*.  Here where you say that a list compares less than an int (and you actually mean a float), you rely on a CPython implementation detail.  It is not strictly speaking part of the python language, and anyway in python3 it will raise an exception.  I really don't see any reason why you use a defaultdict at all here, you aren't taking advantage of its _raison d'être_.

Comment: instead of using a `defaultdict`, it would be clearer to use a plain old dict, and in your loop write `d[key] = min(d.get(key, value), value)`

Comment: You are right. This works because of an implementation detail and it won't work in Python 3. I've updated the code to make that in a more appropriate way. I've also changed the default type of the `dict` from `list` to `None` (`lambda:None`).

Comment: However, I still prefer `defaultdict` over `dict` because when you use `get(key, value)` you are setting a default value for that call if the key doesn't exist, so in both cases you need that default value somewhere. Using `dict` with `get` method may be clearer than `defaultdict` with `None` as default and using the `or` operator, but `defaultdict` comes out to be a bit faster (see the new tests), although the difference is not much.